# How to pass an array of items in React.js

Tags: reactjs

```js
const ListItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <li > {
      this.props.item
    } < /li>;
  }
});

const ToDoList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {

    const todoItems = this.props.items.map(item => {
      return <ListItem item = {
        item
      } > < /ListItem>
    })

    return ( <
      ul > {
        todoItems
      } < /ul>
    );
  }
});

//creating a basic component with no data, just a render function
const MyApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( <
      div className = "well" >
      <
      h1 > Hello < /h1> <
      ToDoList > < /ToDoList> <
      /div>
    );
  }
});

//insert the component into the DOM
ReactDOM.render( < MyApp / > , document.getElementById('container'));



<
div id = "container" > < /div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

A ReactJs tutorial says:

> If we want to make this a truly extensible list, we could create an array of items, then pass them into props through the ToDoList component, then render out each item. Let's do that now.

How can I pass the array of items in the above code?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Data can be passed to components via props.

https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props

In your case props would be accessed inside the components via `this.props`.

`<TodoList />` takes a prop called items which is an array. Inside `<TodoList />` you can map through that array and return elements.

For example in the render method of your class you would return TodoList with a prop of items:

```
const myItems = [{ name: 'item 1' }, { name: 'item2' }];
function MyApp() {
    return (
       <TodoList items={myItems} />
    );
}
```

Then in TodoList you map the items

```
function TodoList({ items }) {
    return items.map(item => (
        <h1>{item.name}</h1>
    ));
}
```

Comment: This code makes me understand how i can manupulate it with objects ,, nice :D

Comment: Can you please explain why we have to put curly brackets around `items` in `TodoList` function? I tried `function TodoList( items )` but it returned errors : *items.map is not a function*

Comment: @Catbuilts That's just the React/Babel syntax

Answer (score 1):

You just set up an attribute, with the same name

```
<ToDoList items={myitems} />
```

Comment: i tried this <ToDoList items=[1,2,3,4]></ToDoList> but it didn't worked

Comment: Can you try <ToDoList items={[1,2,3,4]}></ToDoList>

Comment: say if i wanted the prop item's array to be [1,2,3,4] how should i edit it ?