# "React js" How to pass array data using props?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

```
render() {
   const Array = this.props.students.map((data) => {
      return (
         <button 
           key={data.name}
           //key={data.birthDate}
           //key={data.age}
           //key={data.class}
         >{data.name}</button>
      );
   });

   return (
     <div>
       {Array}
       <StudentInfo name = {"Amira"}/>
     </div> 
   );
}
```

This is my code. Currently I'm trying to pass array data from that `<button></button>` into `<StudentInfo />` and replace the `name = {"Amira"}`
Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please be a little more elaborate as to what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I want to do something like this <StudentInfo name = {data.name}/> is it possible?  
I want the data from the button.{data.name} to be pass to <StudentInfo> but i got error when do this.

Comment: Okay, so you want a single `data.name` or a complete array?

Comment: the complete array

Answer (score 1):

this might be your answer: [How to pass an array of items in REACT.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948828/how-to-pass-an-array-of-items-in-react-js?rq=1)

Comment: and actually I want to do something like this <StudentInfo name = {data.name}/> is it possible?

Comment: I want the data from the button.{data.name} but i got error when do this

Comment: What error are you facing? Check your browser console log and add it to your question, please.

Comment: passing error : unexpected token var
and it also said that code is not valid

Answer (score 1):

Doing this will solve the issue,

```
render() {
   const nameArray = [];
   const Array = this.props.students.map((data) => {
      nameArray.push(data.name); //fill the array with names
      return (
         <button 
           key={data.name}
           //key={data.birthDate}
           //key={data.age}
           //key={data.class}
         >{data.name}</button>
      );
   });

   return (
     <div>
       {Array}
       <StudentInfo name = {nameArray}/>
     </div> 
   );
}
```

Comment: But How if I want it when we click on a button, only data about that person will be display?

Comment: For a button click, you need to add that logic to your question first by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something like this

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.students = [
    {name: 'john'},
    {name: 'paul'},
    {name: 'clara'}
  ];      
  this.state = {
    selectedStudent: this.students[0]
  }
  this.selectStudent = this.selectStudent.bind(this);
}

selectStudent(student){
  this.setState({selectedStudent: student});
}

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      {this.students.map((student, i) => (
        <button key={i}
          onClick={() => this.selectStudent(student)}
        >{student.name}</button>
      ))}
      <h1>{this.state.selectedStudent.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

online demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/91wp5j33pw