# How to check data from array passed through props in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a component which accepts an array as a prop

```
<Component runners={['1','2']}/>
```

Within this functional component, I want to render an element for each value in he array. My logic is:

```
const { runners } = props

if(runners.includes('1')) {
  return(<ElementOne/>)
}

if(runners.includes('2')) {
  return(<ElementTwo/>)
}
```

etc...

the `includes` method throws an error `runners.includes is not a function`. Same for `indexOf`. So I check `typeOf runners` which returns `object`. Then I output `JSON.stringify(runners)`. And it returns "[1,2]".

I try to re-do the above conditionals with `hasOwnProperty` and `in` methods, and they all return false.

Any ideas what might work here?

Comment: I would avoid using the name `prop` as one of your component props.

Comment: @johnborges prop was just an example, sorry. I just edited the code to reflect the real key.

Comment: Why are you destructing props? Is props the name of the property in the functional component. With what I can see, your props should be called runners and you do not need to destructure it,

Comment: This is not an answer but just an observation: you're passing array of strings, but then try to find a number. Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948828/how-to-pass-an-array-of-items-in-react-js ?

Comment: @ahwayakchih that was a typo on my part....I am in fact checking for string

Comment: Can you share bit more on the problem? Which browser etc... Because your code looks totally valid and works: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-rgb-5gips?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `prop` is kind of a special word in `react`

Unless I get the exact code I cannot be sure, but assuming since it is a functional component that probably has `prop` as the argument, the solution is

```
prop.prop.includes(2)
```

the outer prop is the function argument, the inner prop is the actual key you passed to the `Component`

Comment: Thanks...it's not actually called prop I'm just using this as an example. The actuall me of the prop is ```runners```. And I have ``` const { runners } = props ``` above those conditions...so I dont think thats it. JSON.stringify outputs the correct value, but array/obj methods don't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Also add 
ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));
in your index.js from where the react components are basically rendered.

runners -> goes as the props value to the functional component named Prctc(here) and you can use the values of props by using {props.runners} ,since it is array I have iterated it and check the condition provided.Now you can return anything in the enclosing tag.

Comment: Thanks @ayushi! I actually just ended up putting the conditionals as separate const outside the functions which also worked, but this is good too.

Comment: @DanKurfirst please accept the answer if it solves your prblm